# React Native maps get top left corner and bottom right corner latitude and longitude

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I'm working on a react native app which uses React-native-maps , currently i'm stucking with getting current region top left corner (lat & long) and bottom right corner ( lat & long )

```
<MapView.Animated
        onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
        showsUserLocation
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: coords.latitude,
          longitude: coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
      <MapView.Marker
          coordinate={{ latitude: coords.latitude, longitude: coords.longitude }}
      >
      <MapView.Callout style={{ position: 'relative', width: 150}}>
        <PlaceCard />
      </MapView.Callout>
    </MapView.Marker>
</MapView.Animated>
```

any idea for how to get that ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If (`REGION.latitude`, `REGION.longitude`) is the center of the map and the deltas are the distance (in degrees) between the minimum and maximum lat/long displayed on the map then you should be able to get the topLeft and bottomRight points like below:

```
            {
                latlng: {
                    latitude: REGION.latitude+(REGION.latitudeDelta/2),
                    longitude: REGION.longitude-(REGION.longitudeDelta/2)
                },
                title:'topLeft'

            },
            {
                latlng: {
                    latitude: REGION.latitude-(REGION.latitudeDelta/2),
                    longitude: REGION.longitude+(REGION.longitudeDelta/2)
                },
                title:'bottomRight'

            }
```

Comment: Top left or top right ? And bottom right or bottom left ?? , also how can I calculate delta?

Comment: To calculate deltas this link could be useful: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/505. I tested the response from above with a few values(including negative ones) and the markers at topLeft and bottomRight are displayed OK.