# React Native maps get top left corner and bottom right corner latitude and longitude Top left or top right ? And bottom right or bottom left?

Tags: react-native

React Native maps get top left corner and bottom right corner latitude and longitude Top left or top right ? And bottom right or bottom left ??

I'm working on a react native app which uses React-native-maps , currently i'm stucking with getting current region top left corner (lat & long) and bottom right corner ( lat & long )

block of code in react native

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native maps get top left corner and bottom right corner latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743984/react-native-maps-get-top-left-corner-and-bottom-right-corner-latitude-and-longi)